# Существуют ли приложения в Андроид, где разные activity прописывают на разных языках?

Tags: android

Нахожусь в самом начале изучения разработки, поэтому не серчайте, если вопрос глупый.
Существуют ли такие приложения в Андроид Студио, где разные activity прописывают на разных языках, java и kotlin? И, если так все же бывает, то чем это полезно или неполезно?

Comment: а андроид студио вообще не бывает приложений. В андроид студио бывает код для приложений.

Comment: Да, все приложения с Котлином имеют модули на Java. Их можно смешивать в любой пропорции. В частности разные активити могут быть написаны на разных языках.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не вполне понятен. Отвечу на такую его интерпретацию: `Можно ли использовать Java и Kotlin одновременно при написании приложения под Android`.

Можно использовать оба языка - и Java и Kotlin. Однако имеет смысл выбрать только один. Сейчас имеет смысл для нового проекта выбирать Kotlin, в т.ч. т.к. он официально поддерживается и продвигается гуглом как предпочтительный язык для разработки. В нём больше возможностей чем в той версии Java которая поддерживается на Android.

Смешение языков обычно можно встретить в относительно старых проектах, которые были изначально на Java написаны, а новый функционал пишут на Kotlin. И существующий на него переписывают. Обратных случаев в природе почти не встречается, т.к. нет особого смысла.

При этом речь не про активити, а про классы вообще - можно в активити на Java использовать классы написанные на Kotlin, например. И обратное тоже верно - использовать Java классы в коде на Kotlin - можно.